# VS2015 C++ coroutines: promise.get_return_object() return type and coroutine return type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-coroutine

I have a question about Visual Studio 2015 implementation of the Coroutines TS.
[P0057r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0057r5.pdf) working paper states that the coroutine behaves as if its body were:

```
{
    P p;
    auto gro = p.get_return_object();
    co_await p.initial_suspend(); // initial suspend point
    F’
final_suspend:
    co_await p.final_suspend(); // final suspend point
}
```

(§ 8.4.4\3)
and that when a coroutine returns to its caller, the return value is produced as if by the statement `return gro;` (§ 8.4.4\5)

Please note that result of `p.get_return_object()` is stored in variable with `auto` deduced type.

Let coroutine return type be `A` and `promise.get_return_object()` return type be `B`. According to P0057r5 mentioned above variable `gro` should have type `B` (deduced by `auto`) and object of type `A` should be constructed from `gro` when coroutine returns to its caller (for example, using conversion operator in `B` or implicit constructor from `B` in `A`).

In current Visual Studio implementation (compiler version string: "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86") conversion is done after `p.initial_suspend()` and before `F'` gets called as if `gro` type was set to match return type of the coroutine (`A`) and not the return type of `promise.get_return_object()` (`B`).

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Minimal example (compile with /await):

```
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct foo;
struct foo_builder {
    foo_builder() {
        std::cout << "foo_builder constructor\n";
    }
    operator foo();
};

struct foo_promise {
    foo_builder get_return_object() {
        return{};
    }
    void return_value(int value) {
        std::cout << "co_return with " << value << "\n";
    }
    std::experimental::suspend_never initial_suspend() {
        std::cout << "Initial suspend\n";
        return{};
    }
    std::experimental::suspend_never final_suspend() {
        return{};
    }
};

struct foo {
    foo() {
        std::cout << "foo constructor\n";
    }
    using promise_type = foo_promise;
};

foo_builder::operator foo() {
    std::cout << "foo_builder conversion to foo\n";
    return{};
}

foo coroutine() {
    co_return 5;
}

foo simple() {
    foo_promise p;
    auto gro = p.get_return_object();
    // co_await p.initial_suspend(); // initial suspend point

    // co_return 5;
    p.return_value(5); //S;
    goto final_suspend;

final_suspend:
    // co_await p.final_suspend(); // final suspend point
    return gro;
}


int main() {
    auto v = coroutine();

    std::cout << "\nregular function:\n";

    auto v2 = simple();

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Output:

```
Initial suspend
foo_builder constructor
foo_builder conversion to foo
foo constructor
co_return with 5

regular function:
foo_builder constructor
co_return with 5
foo_builder conversion to foo
foo constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing return value of `get_return_object()` by `auto gro` was added in p0057r5. In previous revision (p0057r4) this part reads as

> ...the coroutine behaves as if its body were:

```
{
    P p ;
    co_await p .initial_suspend(); // initial suspend point
    F’
final_suspend :
    co_await p .final_suspend(); // final suspend point
}
```

and

> When a coroutine returns to its caller, the return value is obtained by a call to p.get_return_-
>   object(). A call to a get_return_object is sequenced before the call to initial_suspend and
>   is invoked at most once.

VS2015 obviously implements older version of this paper.